# Cant Uninstall SP3 from SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-pack

I installed SP3 for sql server 2008r2 RTM release on windows server 2008r2. After testing i found some unknown issues in my application. Now i want to downgrade this database engine again into RTM release. I try control panel add/remove option but its remove all database instance. Please suggest

Comment: I think it's quite unlikely that the service pack caused issues in your application. Have you considered troubleshooting instead?

Comment: Actually, this application is very big & doing lot of bulk operations. We suggest them to tune but they said "our application recommended db version is max upto SP2 and we are testing for SP3 and would launch after 3 months". We are also using same instance for some other in-house applications and didn't find any issues. But now downgrade into SP2. Anyhow whatever it is !!! Thankful for your efforts & thoughts !!! Cheers !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try control panel add/remove option but its remove all database instance. Please suggest

That is not exactly the place from where you can uninstall SP, you have to go to add remove programs and then on top left you would see `installed updates`

[image]

Click on view installed updates and you would see all updates for your computer and programs installed on it. Locate SQL Server 2008 R2 Sp3, I have SQL Server 2014 SP2 and it shows like.

Right click on the Service pack and select uninstall.

[image]

Comment: thanks Shanky. Actually I was thinking this tab only for windows securities updates !!!